# Does ‘for the first time’ have two meanings?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

> He made a robot for the first time.

1. The other made a robot earlier than he, but he made a robot for the first time of his life.
2. He is the first person who made a robot, and nobody made a robot before.

Comment: The scope of ***for the first time*** can obviously be context-specific. So *She had sex for the first time last night* clearly means *the first time **in her life***, whereas  *Rutherford split the atom for the first time in 1918* would normally mean *the first time **ever, by anybody*** (we can ignore the possibility that maybe some aliens managed to do this billions of years earlier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that "for the first time" has only one meaning, but it can be interpreted in different ways depending on the context. This is often the case with adverbials, as they can be applied to different parts of a sentence to give different meanings.

This particular sentence can have both of the meanings that you suggested, though the context would probably make the exact meaning clear. If there is no context, the different meanings could be made perfectly clear like this:

> He made his first robot.
> He made the first robot ever.

Comment: Why are you so smart? I’ve never thought of his first robot.